# How do I echo forward slash in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to echo forward slash in php as follows

```
<a class="submenu" href="<?php echo base_url('products').'/'.rawurlencode('Agarbatte/Candle');?>"
```

`Agarbatte/Candle` is not a directory but when i do this, `href` takes this as directory and give me the error page not found.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if its not a directory why are you using the / ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slash in the URL will **always** be treated as a directory separator. And if you replace it with something else you won't have a slash anymore. But that's most likely the easiest solution..

If you have a 1:1 mapping between the path in the URL and your filesystem you are out of luck. If your application uses a "routing layer" though, you can modify it to not treat the `/` as a separator when some criterium is met.

Comment: you didn't get my question. just ignore rawurlencode() function. I want to echo this name `Agarbatte/Candle` on the directed page. but href takes this as directory and finds the file `Candle` in the folder `Agarbatte' but it should be like `products/Agarbatte and Candle`

Comment: use the id corresponding to Agarbatte and Candle. Don't use the String itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'urlencode' on the 'Agarbatte/Candle'. I do not see a special need for 'rawurlencode'.

Comment: you didn't get my question. just ignore rawurlencode() function. I want to echo this name `Agarbatte/Candle` on the directed page. but href takes this as directory and finds the file `Candle` in the folder `Agarbatte' but it should be like `products/Agarbatte and Candle`

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use the `urlencode()` function as others have said, I recommend not getting into this habit. Assuming you have these products in a database, use the `id` and you'll never run into these issues.

For example if the Candle product has `id` of 6 in the database... the PHP should resolve to: `<a class="submenu" href='products/6'>`

Furthermore, there are some shortcuts you can take here which will help you in the long run.

1. Instead of `<?php echo "something" ?>` turn on php short tags in php.ini and use `<?= "something" ?>`
2. You don't need to call `base_url` every time you write a link. Use the `<base>` HTML tag appropriately: `<base href="http://localhost/yourapp/">` in `<head>`

So... with that said after using 1 and 2:

`<a href='products/<?= $id;?>'><?= $name_of_product ?></a>`

Answer (score 0):

how about using  "Agarbatte-Candle" in the url then on the output page

```
$url_bit=string_replace('-','/',$url_bit);
```